# Codeigniter regex to group active filters

Tags: regex, routes, codeigniter-3

I need a way to group url paths under one group till end with something
I need this to get all active filters

> `http://my.website/phones/filter/attribute-id1,attribute-value-id1/attributer-id2,value-id2/c`

And i have REGEX to get the filters
[Click here](https://regex101.com/r/FYxP6z/4)

```
$route['(:any)/(:filter\/(.*)\/c)/c'] = 'test/$1/$2';
```

I tried this but doesn't work.

1. Phone should go in first param
2. All after 'filter' till end with /c goes to param 2

I'm not sure if i'm clear.

Anyone can help me :D

UPDATE

```
function test($category, $filters) {
    print_r($category); // phones
    print_r($filters); // attribute-id1,attribute-value-id1/attributer-id2,value-id2
}
```

Comment: Please show your desired output for the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

`http:\/\/my\.website\/([^\/]+)\/filter\/(.+)\/c`

*1st group* will match `phones`, *2nd group* will match `attribute-id1,attribute-value-id1/attributer-id2,value-id2`.

Comment: I used this

$route['([^\/]+)\/filter\/(.+)\/c'] = 'test/$1/$2'

And still split by '/'

Second group gives - attribute-id1,attribute-value-id1
Third group gives - attributer-id2,value-id2